# MongoDB query for all documents with unique field

Tags: mongodb

I see plenty of responses to the question "how do I get all of the unique values in a field?" which suggest the `.distinct()` method. But this returns a simple array of those values. How do I retrieve all of the documents which HAVE a unique value of a field?

```
[{age: 21, name: 'bob'}, {age: 21, name: 'sally'}, {age: 30, name: 'Jim'}] 
Query for unique age -->
[{age: 21, name: 'sally'}, {age: 30, name: 'Jim'}]
or
[{age: 21, name: 'bob'}, {age: 30, name: 'Jim'}]
```

Filtering a query after-the-fact is not an ideal solution, as I will still want to select, $limit, and $skip as usual.

Comment: what is your criterion for selecting between `sally` and `bob`, if they both have the same age?

Comment: In fact what is the criteria for selecting two documents that are `sally` in general? Which document would you want to return?

Comment: @RyanArtecona You've predicted my follow-up question (how to specify the filter). For my particular use-case I need the "latest" record, but I didn't think it would be necessary to muddy the waters here until seeing how someone would filter at all.

Comment: Next question, how you do know the latest record?

Comment: @Sammaye Guys, all of your comments are ancillary to my question. Let's not put the cart before the horse. Show me *any* way, and I'm sure that it will naturally suggest how to do it a *specific* way.

Comment: `db.col.aggregate([{$group: {_id: '$age', name: {$max: '$name'}}}])` using the new aggregation framework introduced in v2.1

Comment: To answer your edit the aggregation framework is much like SQLs own, so for a limit onto the previous query: `db.col.aggregate([{$group: {_id: '$age', name: {$max: '$name'}}}, {$limit: 10}])` There are so many operators to it take a look: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/

Comment: Thanks, I suspected it might be within `.aggregate()`, but was frankly a little terrified by the concept of a "pipeline". I'll setup a test to verify the syntax. Maybe cut and paste into an answer so I can give some karma once I confirm it works?

Comment: I keep getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'explain' of undefined". Anyone have a demo or example?

Comment: heh yea...the aggregation framework doesnt yet have an explain: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4504 it is coming though, which is what that error says.

Comment: @Sammaye Ha, thanks again. It turns out I was accidentally chaining `.toArray()` after the `.aggregate()` since it used to be a `.find()`. Do you mind putting your comment as an answer so we can button this one up for anyone else who finds it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
> db.foo.insert([{age: 21, name: 'bob'}, {age: 21, name: 'sally'}, {age: 30, name: 'Jim'}])
> db.foo.count()
3
> db.foo.aggregate({ $group: { _id: '$age', name: { $max: '$name' } } }).result
[
    {
        "_id" : 30,
        "name" : "Jim"
    },
    {
        "_id" : 21,
        "name" : "sally"
    }
]
```

Comment: So all of the document needs to be "reconstructed"? What if there had been other properties (eg: height, weight), how do we get the whole record with the `$max: '$name'` and not just pin the max name onto the grouped $age?

Comment: It's just like a SQL "GROUP BY", then if documents have a field called `other_field`, then you should add to your `$group` an expression saying how you want to group that field. See the `name: { $max: '$name' }` expression in my example.

Comment: That will give you the info a person who doesn't necessarily exist, `{ "_id: 30", name: "max name from those with id 30", other_field: "max other_field from those with id 30"}`. (before you edited). So what's the command to get the other_field from the record with the $max: '$name'?

Comment: Good point - use $first or $last in place of $max, to consistently choose all fields' values from the first- or last-encountered document in each group:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/first/#_S_first

Comment: Ya, I ended up using a big 'ole pile of $last. I guess I was just sad to have to "recreate" a document instead of "picking" it from the group. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Vote for https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4437 and / or https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8065 -- both tickets are kind of vague, but it seems like if either feature request is implemented you'd get the ability to filter out all but the nth document in the group and output that entire document (e.g., "group docs by age and sort by name descending, give me the whole first document in the age group").

Answer (score 2):

Hi I am a newbie mongo dev, I have been struggling with the same question and I was finally able to figure out a solution. I am using aggregate pipeline with the following steps:

1. group: with `_id` as `age`
2. lookup: use `_id` from step 1. inside the same collection with local field as `_id` and foreign field as `age`, save the lookup to a new list `ob`.
3. replaceRoot: ie. replace the root of each result so far with the first object from `ob` list from step 2.

There maybe better solutions out there. If someone finds it please let us know. Hope the solution helps.

DB:

```
[
  {
    age: 21,
    name: "bob"
  },
  {
    age: 21,
    name: "sally"
  },
  {
    age: 30,
    name: "Jim"
  }
]
```

Aggregatation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$age"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "age",
      as: "ob"
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $first: "$ob"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
    "age": 30,
    "name": "Jim"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "age": 21,
    "name": "bob"
  }
]
```

mongoplayground:

[Playground solution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lFD07jQRYMC)