# MongoDB: distinct tuples

Tags: mongodb, distinct

Suppose to have a collection of MongoDB documents with the following structure:

```
{
    id_str:     "some_value",
    text:       "some_text",
    some_field: "some_other_value"
}
```

I would like to filter such documents so as to obtain the ones with *distinct text values*.

I learned from the MongoDB documentation how to extract unique field values from a collection, using the [`distinct`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) operation. Thus, by performing the following query:

```
db.myCollection.distinct("text")
```

I would obtain an array containing the distinct text values:

```
["first_distinct_text", "second_distinct_text",...]
```

However, this is not the result that i would like to obtain. Instead, I would like to have the following:

```
{ "id_str": "a_sample_of_id_having_first_distinct_text", 
  "text": "first_distinct_text"}
{ "id_str": "a_sample_of_id_having_second_distinct_text", 
  "text": "second_distinct_text"}
```

I am not sure if this can be done with a single query.

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697332/mongodb-query-for-all-documents-with-unique-field/14697970#14697970) which, however, do not solve fully my problem.

Do you have any hint on how to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean documents where `id_str != text != some_field`?

Comment: No. `some_field` would be ignored. `text` has to be unique. `id_str` should be picked at random from the set of documents reporting the same `text` field. So if I have: `{id_str:123,text:"hello"}` and `{id_str:456,text:hello}`, the result could be either `{id_str:123,text:"hello"}` or `{id_str:456,text:hello}`, since they have the same text and it does not matter whether you select "123" or "456" as `id_str`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into making an [aggregate query](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) using the `$group` stage, and probably using the `$first` operator.

Maybe something along the lines of:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([{ $group : { _id : { text: "$text"},
                                        text: { $first: "$id_str" }
                                      }
                           }])
```

Comment: Can you provide me with an example of usage?

Comment: In this way text is duplicated. Maybe you meant to put `$id_str` with `$first`?

Comment: Yes, `$id_str` should be with `$first`, sorry

Comment: @Eleanore: If the answer was helpful to you, please consider accepting the answer :).

Comment: I think this might be slow since `$group` can't utilize indexes: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32841857/1517969

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 db.myCollection.aggregate({$group: {_id: {'text': "$text", 'id_str': '$id_str'}}})
```

More information here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/

Comment: I tried. It still gives duplicates on the `text` field, since the `id_str` field contains non-duplicate fields