# MongoDB Aggregation seems very slow

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb instance running with the following stats:

```
{
    "db" : "s",
    "collections" : 4,
    "objects" : 1.23932e+008,
    "avgObjSize" : 239.9999891553412400,
    "dataSize" : 29743673136.0000000000000000,
    "storageSize" : 32916655936.0000000000000000,
    "numExtents" : 39,
    "indexes" : 3,
    "indexSize" : 7737839984.0000000000000000,
    "fileSize" : 45009076224.0000000000000000,
    "nsSizeMB" : 16,
    "dataFileVersion" : {
        "major" : 4,
        "minor" : 5
    },
    "extentFreeList" : {
        "num" : 0,
        "totalSize" : 0
    },
    "ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}
```

I'm trying to run the following query:

```
db.getCollection('tick_data').aggregate(
    [       
        {$group: {_id: "$ccy",min:{$first: "$date_time"},max:{$last: "$date_time"}}}

    ]
)
```

And I have the following index set-up in the collection:

```
{
    "ccy" : 1,
    "date_time" : 1
}
```

The query takes 510 seconds to run, which feels like it's extremely slow even though the collection is fairly large (~120 million documents). Is there a simple way for me to make this faster?

Every document has the structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56095bd7b2fc3e36d8d6ed52"),
    "bid_volume" : "6.00",
    "date_time" : ISODate("2007-01-01T00:00:07.904Z"),
    "ccy" : "USDNOK",
    "bid" : 6.2271700000000001,
    "ask_volume" : "6.00",
    "ask" : 6.2357699999999996
}
```

Results of explain:

```
{
    "stages" : [ 
        {
            "$cursor" : {
                "query" : {},
                "fields" : {
                    "ccy" : 1,
                    "date_time" : 1,
                    "_id" : 0
                },
                "plan" : {
                    "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "scanAndOrder" : false,
                    "allPlans" : [ 
                        {
                            "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "scanAndOrder" : false
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : "$ccy",
                "min" : {
                    "$first" : "$date_time"
                },
                "max" : {
                    "$last" : "$date_time"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}
```

Thanks

Comment: It's slow is it? 520 seconds would seem slow. Seemingly there is no sharding structure or sufficient memory to handle the collection data ( individually or on nodes ), not to mention you are actually asking to aggregate the whole collection in the first place. Over the sort of data size you are talking about this is entirely architecture dependent. If you are actually just throwing this at one big node then the results are more or less expected. Note that this is likely already running "off-topic" for the reasons already mentioned.

Comment: Can you try  explain, I have a doubt that it's using index

Comment: @RohitJain There is only a `$group` stage and no `$match`. The `$match` and other "special query" stages are the only things that can use an index. So your comment has no relevance here.

Comment: I've added the results of the explain

Comment: Currently the database is running on a linux server with 4gb of RAM and 2 processors.....maybe that's just not going to be enough to cut it...

Comment: Try this -  db.getCollection('tick_data').aggregate(
    [   { $sort: { ccy: 1, date_time: 1 } },
        {$group: {_id: "$ccy",min:{$first: "$date_time"},max:{$last: "$date_time"}}}

    ]
)

Comment: Thanks Rohit, but that query took 575 seconds. I will try to upgrade the server (AWS instance) and see if that has much of an effect. Would like to avoid sharding if possible due to extra complexity

Comment: If I increase the server to have 8 processors and 32gb RAM then the query takes half the time (260 seconds)......This still feels very slow to me!

Comment: tick_data.find({"ccy":"USDCHF"}).sort({"date_time":-1}).limit(1) takes 0.001 seconds to run...and tick_data.distinct("ccy") takes 0.001 seconds.....so I don't understand why doing the $group with aggregation is taking so long

Comment: I haven't verified it, but maybe [$first optimization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html#optimization-to-return-the-first-document-of-each-group) could be used if one ensure the index is sorted in descending order. (`$last` does not seem to have the same optimization - though tested on a old mongob version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I wrote a function which takes 0.002 seconds to run.

```
function() {
    var results = {}
    var ccys = db.tick_data.distinct("ccy");
    ccys.forEach(function(ccy)
        {
            var max_results = []
            var min_results = []

            db.tick_data.find({"ccy":ccy},{"date_time":1,"_id":0}).sort({"date_time":1}).limit(1).forEach(function(v){min_results.push(v.date_time)})
            db.tick_data.find({"ccy":ccy},{"date_time":1,"_id":0}).sort({"date_time":-1}).limit(1).forEach(function(v){max_results.push(v.date_time)})

            var max = max_results[0]
            var min = min_results[0]
            results[ccy]={"max_date_time":max,"min_date_time":min}
        }
    )
    return results
}
```

Comment: Nice :) Unfortunately `distinct` can't find tuples, so out of luck in the general case

Answer (score 2):

As mentionned already by @Blakes Seven, $group cannot use indexes. See [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20455752/mongodb-aggregation-framework-does-group-use-index).

Thus, your query is already optimal. A possible way to optimise this usecase is to pre-calculate and persist the data in a side collection.

You could try this data structure :

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("560a5139b56a71ea60890201"),
  "ccy" : "USDNOK",
  "date_time_first" : ISODate("2007-01-01T00:00:07.904Z"),
  "date_time_last" : ISODate("2007-09-09T00:00:07.904Z")
}
```

Querying this can be done in milliseconds instead of 500+ seconds and you can benefit from indexes.

Then of course, each time you add, update or delete a document from the main collection, you would need to update the side collection.

Depending on how badly you need the data to be "fresh", you could also choose to skip this "live update process" and regenerate entirely the side collection only once a day with a batch and keep in mind that your data may not be "fresh".

Another problem you could fix : Your server definitely needs more RAM & CPU. Your working set probably doesn't fit in RAM, especially with this kind of aggregations.

Also, you can probably make good use of an SSD and I would **STRONGLY** recommand using a 3 nodes Replicaset instead of a single instance for production.

Comment: I think it's going to be fastest for me to run a tick_data.distinct("ccy"), then send a find({"ccy"=ccy}).sort({"date_time":-1}).limit(1) query for each ccy to get the max dates...then do the same with ascending sort order for the min dates

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on database architecture