# Query documents and result should contain unique fields value MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have the same question as asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697332/mongodb-query-for-all-documents-with-unique-field) but i don't really understand the solution.

I have tried to `aggregate` and use the `$group` field in the pipeline but when i have tried it, it only returns the values inside the $group and not the whole documents.

I want to retrieve let's say 20 documents based on several conditions and the result should contain a unique field value.

Here is an example document :

```
{
  "_id": "uid1",
  "public": true,
  "closed": false,
  "userID": "userID1",
  "url": "url1"
}
```

Now let's say i also have :

```
{
  "_id": "uid2",
  "public": true,
  "closed": false,
  "userID": "userID2",
  "url": "url2"
},
{
  "_id": "uid3",
  "public": true,
  "closed": false,
  "userID": "userID1",
  "url": "url3"
},
{
  "_id": "uid4",
  "public": true,
  "closed": true,
  "userID": "userID3",
  "url": "url4"
}
```

The query i am looking for should retrieve :

```
{
  "_id": "uid1",
  "public": true,
  "closed": false,
  "userID": "userID1",
  "url": "url1"
},
{
  "_id": "uid2",
  "public": true,
  "closed": false,
  "userID": "userID2",
  "url": "url2"
}
```

OR

```
{
  "_id": "uid3",
  "public": true,
  "closed": false,
  "userID": "userID1",
  "url": "url3"
},
{
  "_id": "uid2",
  "public": true,
  "closed": false,
  "userID": "userID2",
  "url": "url2"
}
```

By querying with `{"closed": false, "public": true}`, and `userID` must be unique in the results.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Would be great if you can share the complete query. Or create a demo in MongoPlayground. Thanks.

Comment: I am actually asking for the query as an answer, i don't know how how to write it unfortunately. I have simply pasted the output to help you understand what i expect

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/wHFrV6fHxwU something like this?

Comment: this is almost perfect, i can work with that ! 
Is it possible to have a condition that doesn't always select "uid1" but also "uid3" ?

Comment: $last for second output instead of $first

Comment: Sorry, i meant a random between both ? when i run the playground 10 times, it would be nice to have a random 4-5 times uid1 and 5-6 times uid3 for example

in my real query i will have thousands of records with `userID1` so i don't want it retrieve always the $first in order

Comment: i dont know if it is possible to do this in the query itself maybe in python you can do something like `"randomDoc": {random.choice(["$first", "$last"]): "$$ROOT"}`

Comment: i think you will have to go with the above. not possible to randomly run different conditions in the mongo query itself

Comment: Here's a [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8ZvCZekVVpu) that randomly selects the document after `"$group"`.

Comment: Sorry i thought i had answered, it's exactly what i needed thank you !